# The route template cannot start with a '~' character in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

Using the Microsoft ASP.NET Core framework and C# language, I am building a Web REST server, that must respond to requests whose path begins with the string "~app". So, I wrote these lines:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("~app")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase ...
```

Though, when the following lines are executed:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

the following exception is raised:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=The route template cannot start with a '~' character unless followed by a '/'. (Parameter 'routeTemplate')
Inner Exception 1:
RoutePatternException: The route template cannot start with a '~' character unless followed by a '/'.
```

Why the tilde character is not allowed in the request path?

EDIT: How can I respond to requests whose path begins with the string "~app"?

Answer (score 0):

`~` at start is [special character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis) in route templates (and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#combining-attribute-routes)).

The following code applies `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]` to the controller:

```cs
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/")]
    [Route("/Home")]
    [Route("~/Home/Index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo();
    }
}
```

> In the preceding code, the Index method templates must prepend `/` or `~/` to the route templates. Route templates applied to an action that begin with `/` or `~/` don't get combined with route templates applied to the controller

> Route templates applied to an action that begin with `/` or `~/` don't get combined with route templates applied to the controller.

Comment: So, how can I respond to requests whose path begins with the string "~app"?